# Status bar not chancing text

Tags: statusbar

So when I am working on firefox, everytime I switch tab, the text on the top left status bar changes to the page title. How do I change it that the text is static, and displays the application name?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Patch Firefox to not change the page title, or write an extension which overrides all page titles to be "Mozilla Firefox" would be the only ways.

Comment: Sorry, you probably misunderstood. It is not just for firefox, but for all the programs. If that is not possible, still, thanks for your time!

Comment: It is not possible. It is the titlebar text of the app. The app decides what it puts in the titlebar text.

Comment: Okay, is there a way to change what the app puts in the titlebar?